# Using tabularray by defining "\\" in a different way

Tags: tables, lyx, tabularray

I want to use `tabularray` tables in `lyx` by redefining `tabular` environment. For this aim, I need to use `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\` by `\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}`. But, if I do this, the table is corrupted as in the figure. What is the reason for this, and how to tackle it?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\begin{document}

\Large{WRONG}: 
\begin{tblr}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \SetRow{lime!20} Item 1 & Item 2 & Item 3 \tabularnewline
    \hline
    text & text & text\tabularnewline
    \hline
\end{tblr}

\vspace{1cm}

\Large{RIGHT}: 
\begin{tblr}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \SetRow{lime!20} Item 1 & Item 2 & Item 3 \\
    \hline
    text & text & text\\
    \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might be interested in a module i wrote to use tabularray in lyx. You can get it here: https://github.com/Udi-Fogiel/LyX-Tabularray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tabularray` must see a real `\\` because it uses that to split the array in rows. So you must tell it to expand `\tabularnewline` first with `[expand=\tabularnewline]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\begin{document}

\Large{RIGHT}: 
\begin{tblr}[expand=\tabularnewline]{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \SetRow{lime!20} Item 1 & Item 2 & Item 3 \tabularnewline
    \hline
    text & text & text\tabularnewline
    \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```