# \tabularnewline not recognised in tabularray?

Tags: tabularray

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section{All good here}

\begin{tblr}{lccr}
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Delta \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta & Theta \\
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda & Mu \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\section{Pb here}

\begin{tblr}{lccr}
\hline
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Delta \tabularnewline 
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta & Theta \tabularnewline 
\hline
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda & Mu \tabularnewline 
\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `incompatible` is probably the wrong term here. In the LaTeX kernel `\tabularnewline` is only defined inside `\@array`, it is `\relax` everywhere else. You could register an issue about it on `tabularray`s github. BTW: you can see the definition via `\typeout{\meaning\tabularnewline}` inside a cell. Compare to what you get if you use `tabular` instead of `tblr`.

Comment: @daleif  [done !](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/209) . nice trick `\typeout{\meaning`... Merci !

Comment: @JeT I can not understand why you want to use a quite long name `\tabularnewline`? Can you show your use case?

Comment: @L.J.R. I could not disagree but **1.** I follow this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78798/163874), and **2.** I try to apply your package with other packages like `acro` or `tcolorbox` that seem to prefer `\tabularray`. I will send 2 questions on this, sure you'll be able to help me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78798/163874) you gave, you can see it is just a workaround to use `\tabularnewline` in traditional `tabular` environment, because of the limitation of `tabular`. But `tabularray` is quite different in implementation from `tabular` and it doesn't have this limitation. Therefore you need not and should not use `\tabularnewline` any more in general.

In case you really need to use `\tabularnewline`, you can define `\tabularnewline` as `\\` and use `expand` option in a `tabularray` table, see this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/630777/using-tabularray-by-defining-in-a-different-way).

If you find problems in applying `tabularray` with other packages like `acro` or `tcolorbox`, you may ask some new questions for them.