# Redefine \\ for multiline cells in tabularray

Tags: tabularray

When using multiline cells with tabularray like in the example below, I have the problem that my editor (emacs) recognizes the `\\` that indicate a newline in a cell as the end of a row and thus messes up aligning the table in the editor. So is there a way to use another command instead of `\\` for the multiline cells or map it to another macro. I tried `\newcommand{\nl}{\\}`, but this doesn' work (it stretches the table to the right).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={clr},hlines}
    one & {left\\leftttt} & three          \\
    one & two             & {right\\rightttt} \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

(Example from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/610110/21557)).

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/630796/250119 for a working hack for that. (also maybe ask L.J.R to implement it "officially" as a feature (possibly with a warning), it's not like tabularnewline has another usage anyway)

Comment: You could use `\cr` whithin tables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use your `\nl` command to break multiline cells by using `varwidth` library of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package (and you don't need to enclose them with curly braces):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\SetTblrInner[tblr]{measure=vbox}
\newcommand{\nl}{\\}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec={clr},hlines}
  one                 & left\nl leftttt & three             \\
  center\nl centerrrr & two             & right\nl rightttt \\
\end{tblr}

\bigskip

\begin{tblr}{colspec={clr},hlines}
  one                 & {left\\leftttt} & three             \\
  {center\\centerrrr} & two             & {right\\rightttt} \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]